# @_implementationOnly no apple docs or status about it

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

`@_implementationOnly` import XXX

I would like to use but there is no any Apple documentation about it

- do you know where I can find some official Apple docs about it?
- what's the minimum Swift version supported for it?
- is it still in beta or is it stable and official to use?

Answer (score 2):

Generally all underscored properties and methods are not for regular usage (they tend to be either private APIs or development features).  From the apple repo docs:

> ## Underscored Attributes Reference
>
> **WARNING:** This information is provided primarily for compiler and standard library developers. Usage of these attributes outside of the
> Swift monorepo is STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.

Comment: I guess that you are referring to this
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md

Comment: They're referring to a macro that allows for implementation only imports. It's not documented but it is widely used in the Firebase iOS library.

Answer (score 2):

For information `@_implementationOnly` is getting formalized by this proposal [SE-0409: Access-level modifiers on import declarations](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0409-access-level-on-imports.md)

Some linked discussions can be seen here:

- https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0409-access-level-modifiers-on-import-declarations/67290/22
- https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-with-modifications-se-0409-access-level-modifiers-on-import-declarations/67666

As far I can see it has been released yet (15/01/2024): https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

So there isn't any documentation about this API but there is public usage of it that you can look at.

To answer your questions:

- **do you know where I can find some official Apple docs about it?**

You can take a look at `Firebase`'s code to see usage of it. You can go to the repo and look around for implementations but [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/acf4b8268865e2d2f417f3cab95d92c4c65d1b85/FirebaseFunctions/Sources/Internal/FunctionsComponent.swift#L22) is a specific file you can look at with a brief note about usage from `Google`.

- **what's the minimum Swift version supported for it?**

I can't tell you this for sure but the `Firebase` library supports these platforms and versions: `iOS 11+`, `Mac Catalyst 13+`, `macOS 10.13+`, `tvOS 12`, `watchOS 7`. This reference can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/acf4b8268865e2d2f417f3cab95d92c4c65d1b85/Package.swift#L26).

Additionally, it appears that the library supports Swift Tools version 5.6 according to `Firebase`'s `Package.Swift` file found [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/acf4b8268865e2d2f417f3cab95d92c4c65d1b85/Package.swift#L1) since `April, 4th 2023` according to the `Git` history.

- **is it still in beta or is it stable and official to use?**

I can't answer that. I can tell you that `Google` is using it in production and has been since `May, 23rd 2022` according to the [Git history](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blame/acf4b8268865e2d2f417f3cab95d92c4c65d1b85/FirebaseFunctions/Sources/Internal/FunctionsComponent.swift#L22).